# Django middleware get dynamic url param value

Tags: django

```
path('<int:id>/', views.client),
```

I have a middleware and I need to get  from url. I have try to put inside of `__call__(self, request, id)`, but its not working. anyone know how to achieve this

```
class SimpleMiddleware:
    def __init__(self, get_response):
        self.get_response = get_response

    def __call__(self, request, id): <---error

        from django.http import HttpResponse
        return HttpResponse('before middleware' + id) <----error

        response = self.get_response(request)

        from django.http import HttpResponse
        return HttpResponse('after middleware')

        return response
```

Comment: AFAIK, you can't get URL parameter directly in middleware. What you can do (at least) is get the URL path info by [**`request.path`**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/request-response/#django.http.HttpRequest.path) attribute

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[You can get the URL resolver information in the `process_view` function of a middleware class.](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/http/middleware/#process-view)

```
class SimpleMiddleware:
    def process_view(request, view_func, view_args, view_kwargs):
        pass
```